# How to start certain number of nodes in Redis cluster

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

To create and start a cluster in Redis, I use create-cluster.sh file inside

> /redis-3.04/utils/create-cluster

With the use of this I can create as many nodes I want by changing the:

**Settings**

```
PORT=30000 
TIMEOUT=2000 
NODES=10 
REPLICAS=1.
```

I wonder if I can create for example 10 nodes (5 masters with 5 slaves) in the beginning but start only 4 masters and 4 slaves (meet and join).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean meet and join ? Will the masters share data or are you using nodes as shards to divide the load ?

Comment: The background idea is that i have some nodes in my cluster in order to serve requests. When the load of these nodes exceeds a defined by me threshold i migrate some of the load to a new idle master.But i need the idle master to be in the cluster. How to have 5 masters but initially begin only 4? That is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can add more nodes if load increase on your existing cluster .

Basic Steps are :

1. Start new redis instances - Let's say you want to add 2 more master and there slaves (Total 4 redis instances)
2. Then using redis-trib utility do following :

   `redis-trib.rb add-node <new master node:port> <any existing master>`
   e.g. `./redis-trib.rb add-node 192.168.1.16:7000 192.168.1.15:7000`
3. After this new node will be assigned an id . Note that id and run following command to add slave to node that we added in prev step

   `/redis-trib.rb add-node --slave --master-id <master-node-id> <new-node> <master-node>`
   `./redis-trib.rb add-node --slave --master-id 6f9db976c3792e06f9cd252aec7cf262037bea4a 192.168.1.17:7000 192.168.1.16:7000`
   where 6f9db976c3792e06f9cd252aec7cf262037bea4a is id of 192.168.1.16:7000.
4. Using similar steps you can add 1 more master-slave pair .
5. Since these node do not contains any slots to serve, you have move some of the slots from existing masters to new masters .( **Re-Sharding**)
6. To that you can run following command/**Resharding steps** :

   6.1 `./redis-trib.rb reshard <any-master-ip>:<master-port>`

   6.2 It will ask :  **How many slots do you want to move (from 1 to 16384)?**  => Enter number of slots you want to move

   6.3 Then it will ask : **What is the receiving node ID?**

   6.4 Enter node id to which slots need to be moved  . (new masters)

   6.5 It will prompt :
   **Please enter all the source node IDs.**
   **Type 'all' to use all the nodes as source nodes for the hash slots.**
   **Type 'done' once you entered all the source nodes IDs.**
   **Source node #1:**  (*enter source node id or all*)

   6.6 Then it will prompt info saying Moving slot n to node node-id like

   Moving slot 10960 from 37d10f18f349a6a5682c791bff90e0188ae35e49
   Moving slot 10961 from 37d10f18f349a6a5682c791bff90e0188ae35e49
   Moving slot 10962 from 37d10f18f349a6a5682c791bff90e0188ae35e49

   6.7 It will ask : **Do you want to proceed with the proposed reshard plan (yes/no)?**   Type `Yes` and enter and *you are done* .

**Note :** If data is large it might take some time to reshard.

Few Commands :

1. To know all nodes in cluster  and cluster nodes with node ids:

   redis-cli -h node-ip -p node-port cluster nodes

   e.g. redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 7000 cluster nodes
2. To know all slots in cluster :

   redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 7000 cluster slots

Ref : https://redis.io/commands/cluster-nodes

*Hope this will help .*

Comment: Great answer with lot of information. Also, i find that you can start an instance using create-cluster.sh, reshard and then add it into the cluster programmatically

Comment: @Antonis Please upvote the answer if it really helped you.